# Comment in twig expression

Tags: twig

I'm making a twig macro that has a multi-line object.

```
{% set someVar = {
    'foo': 'bar',
    'foo': 'bar',
    'foo': 'bar',
    'foo': 'bar',
    'foo': 'bar',
    'foo': 'bar',
    'foo': 'bar',
    'foo': 'bar',
    'foo': 'bar',
    'foo': 'bar',
} %}
```

Now I want to group the lines and add some comments to not confuse the reader.  The below doesn't work. Is there another way?

```
{% set someVar = {
    'foo': 'bar',
    {# The below lines do bla-bla #}
    'foo': 'bar',
    'foo': 'bar',
} %}
```

Comment: could you post the not working code, please?

Comment: @Matteo done...

Comment: Nope, i'd say put the comment above the `set`

Comment: @DarkBee That is defeating the purpose of the comments I want to add. I need to group lines into categories and label them. Are you saying it's not possible? That seems like a rather annoying limitation of twig.

Comment: Don't see how this is a limitation to `twig`. Templates should be used to display data, not arrange/group them. Anyhow you could do the [following](https://twigfiddle.com/eblp6d) which gives you some "overhead"

Comment: How is it not a limitation? In PHP you can do that perfectly fine. And don't make this X/Y please, commenting in a template is perfectly valid. Also, commenting the entire block is useless.

Comment: Then the short answer is, no not possible